# XSLT: my transform add an unselected element. What am I missing?

Tags: xslt

Ok, I'm working through some simple tutorials from here:

http://www.cch.kcl.ac.uk/legacy/teaching/7aavdh06/xslt/html/module_06.html

The first exercise involves creating a transformation that produces a certain output.  Unfortunately, although I'm close, I get an unwanted element at the start.  i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xhtml"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />

  <xsl:template match="/div/placeName">
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <Table>
          <tr>
            <td>Place Name</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Place Name (regularised)</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@reg" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>National Grid Reference</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@key" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Type of building/monument</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="settlement/@type" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </Table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the output I'm getting is:

```
Location
Place Name  Old Warden
Place Name (regularised)    Old Warden, St Leonard
National Grid Reference TL 137 443
Type of building/monument   Parish church
```

The rest is fine but the 'Location' is unwanted.  The source XML is at the link above.  Any idea how I stop the unwanted text appearing?  Or, better still, tell me where I'm going wrong! :)

Edit:  Here is the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
Location
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Place Name</td>
            <td>Old Warden</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Place Name (regularised)</td>
            <td>Old Warden,  St Leonard</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>National Grid Reference</td>
            <td>TL 137 443</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Type of building/monument</td>
            <td>Parish church</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello! It would also really help if you added the input XML to your question too, to save folk having to click through (and links can, and do, break too, which wouldn't help in the future). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xhtml" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
<xsl:template match="div">
<xsl:apply-templates select="placeName"/>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="placeName">
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <Table>
          <tr>
            <td>Place Name</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Place Name (regularised)</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@reg" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>National Grid Reference</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@key" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Type of building/monument</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="settlement/@type" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </Table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Steve - You get the "location" in the output as the built in template is applied.

Comment: Gah!  Thanks for that, Shil.  I was pretty close otherwise :)

Answer (score 2):

As Stivel mentions, the "Location" text does come from the **head** element in your XML.

```
<div type="location">
    <head n="I">Location</head>
    <placeName reg="Old Warden,  St Leonard" key="TL 137 443">
```

The reason it is appearing is because of XSTL's built-in templates which it uses when you do not specify a match for an element it is looking for in your XSLT.

You can read up on built-in templates at the [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) but in short, if XSLT can't find a match it will either continue processing the element's children (without copying the element), or in the case of text or attributes, output the value.

XSLT will start by looking for a match for the document element first, and if you have not provided a template, it will continue looking for a template for the root element, and then its children, and so on.

In your case, you have not provided a template to match anything until **/div/placeName**, this means XSLT will use the built-in template for the **div** element. This has two children; **head** and **placeName**. You have a template it can use for **placeName**, but not **head** and so the built-in template ends up outputing the text for **head** because you have not told it anything otherwise.

The solution is to simply to add a template to ignore the **head** element

```
<xsl:template match="/div/head" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xhtml"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/div/head" />

  <xsl:template match="/div/placeName">
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <Table>
          <tr>
            <td>Place Name</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Place Name (regularised)</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@reg" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>National Grid Reference</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@key" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Type of building/monument</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="settlement/@type" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </Table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you use this, this should give the output you need.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Tim.  It helps my understanding a lot (and other people who come across this question in future)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `<head/>` may refer

```
<head n="I">Location</head>
```

remove `<head/>` in xsl and check that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm afraid it isn't that.  The 'Location' actually appears here: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    Location
    <!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM...  I've added the output to the question to make things clearer.